# React Native Navigation - npm run android build error on React Native v0.59

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, wix-react-native-navigation, react-native-navigation-v2

Detail:

- **"react-native": "0.59.0"**
- **"react-native-navigation": "^2.13.1"**

I already followed the installation instructions on [here](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/Installing). But when I do command line `npm run android` or `react-native run-android` I got errors like this

> Task :react-native-navigation:compileReactNative57_5DebugJavaWithJavac
>   /Users/vive/Documents/Projects/RNPlayground/node_modules/react-native-navigation/lib/android/app/src/main/java/com/reactnativenavigation/
>   views/element/Element.java:17: error: ReactViewBackgroundDrawable is not public in com.facebook.react.views.view; cannot be accessed from out
>   side package
>   import com.facebook.react.views.view.ReactViewBackgroundDrawable;

### How to solve this issue? Anyone have any idea? Thank you.

**ISSUE SOLVED** :
Just realize that I missed something in the installing step. Got hint from [here](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4623#issuecomment-457091955)

Comment: this issue is not about installation, where you using `ReactViewBackgroundDrawable `

Comment: Is about the installation. Just realize missed something on tutorial step. Fixed on this [dicussion](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/4874)